# Symfony FOSuser translation new form

Tags: doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony

I have problem with translation of new inputs in the registration form in FOSUSER. Basicly I Extended the FOS user Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     */
    class User extends BaseUser {

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         *
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Fill it", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
         * @Assert\Length(
         *     min=3,
         *     max=255,
         *     minMessage="To short.",
         *     maxMessage="To long.",
         *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
         * )
         */
        protected $nameU;

        public function getNameU() {
            return $this->nameU;
        }

     public function setNameU($nameU) {
            $this->nameU= $nameU;
        }
```

Ovveride the registration FORM

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Type\CaptchaType;

use FOS\UserBundle\Util\LegacyFormHelper;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nameU')

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';

        // Or for Symfony < 2.8
        // return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

In my registration view I have:

```
{{ form_label(form.nameU, null,{}) }}
```

Add to translation specific declaration for a locale of FOS USER BUNDLE in app/Resource/FosUser../translation/.....

```
form:
    group_name: Gruppenname
    username: Benutzername  TEST  <- this change OK
    nameU: TESTS    <- this not
```

The translation is not working and it's look like variable name nameU :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found it. I forget to send it in the registration type:

```
    class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->
                ->add('numeU',null, array('label' => 'form.nameU', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
```